# Dask: LocalCluster scheduler not using all cores and slower than default threaded scheduler?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I am using dask array to speed up computations on a single machine (either 4-core or 32 core) using either the default "threads" scheduler or the dask.distributed LocalCluster (threads, no processes).

Given that the dask.distributed scheduler is newer and comes with a a nice dashboard, I was hoping to use this scheduler. However, I found that the LocalCluster scheduler is slower (by a factor 2 or more) than the default scheduler. The LocalCluster scheduler also did not fully utilize all requested cores, and occasionally on the 32-core machine just used just one or a few.

Question: is this expected behavior? If not, what can I do to improve the performance of the LocalCluster scheduler?

Below is the code I used for testing, an example output (run on 4-core machine) and a snapshot of the system monitor following the test.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np

import dask.array as  da
import dask.distributed

from datetime import datetime

n_threads= 4
n = 40_000

def test(n=40_000, chunk=1000):
    da.random.seed(731)
    x = da.random.random((n,n), chunks=(chunk,chunk))
    y = x + x.T
    z = y[::2,5000:].mean(axis=1)
    return z

print("Test default threads scheduler (size={}, {} threads)".format(n, n_threads))

start = datetime.now()
result1 = test(n=n).compute(scheduler="threads", num_workers=n_threads)

print("Done in {}".format(datetime.now()-start))

print("Test dask distributed LocalCluster scheduler (size={}, {} threads)".format(n, n_threads))

client = dask.distributed.Client(processes=False, n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=n_threads)
print("Client: ", client)

start = datetime.now()
result2 = test(n=n).compute()

print("Done in {}".format(datetime.now()-start))

client.close()


error = np.mean(np.abs(result1-result2))

print("Mean absolute difference between results: {}".format(error))
```

**Output**

```
>> python test_dask.py
Test default threads scheduler (size=40000, 4 threads)
Done in 0:00:09.872372
Test dask distributed LocalCluster scheduler (size=40000, 4 threads)
Client:  <Client: 'inproc://192.168.0.129/32574/1' processes=1 threads=4, memory=16.67 GB>
Done in 0:00:18.028071
Mean absolute difference between results: 0.0
```

**CPU and Memory usage**

(default threads scheduler from ~43-53 seconds, LocalCluster from ~23-45 seconds)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Numpy workloads typically do work well with many threads as opposed to many processes, because the underlying operations release the GIL, and with threads you minimise memory copies.

The distributed scheduler (i.e., LocalCluster) allows you to choose your mix of processes and threads, and indeed can work *in-process* too (although this is rarer). See the [long list of arguments](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html#distributed.deploy.local.LocalCluster), particularly `n_workers`, `threads_per_worker` and `processes`. If you have one worker and many threads, you should have something similar to the non-distributed threaded scheduler.

Note, however, that the distributed scheduler is more complicated than the default threaded one. This usually means smarter performance, but always means more per-task overhead/latency. You will feel that when the execution time of each task is very short, which may well be the case for your simple numpy operations.